# mvn package cannot find jars installed in local repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project which has dependencies on two of my other projects.  I have used `mvn package` to create jar files of the two projects and then got them installed into my local repository successfully.  They are installed in the `localrepository/com` folder of the local repository.

In my third project I have added the dependencies of the two projects in the Pom.xml.  There are no errors running the project on `eclipse`.  However when I run the command `mvn package` for this project on command-line, it throws error that it

> cannot resolve the dependencies for my two projects from the central
>   repository

.  I then run the `mvn -o package` command to run `mvn` offline, however I again get error that

> mvn is being run offline and that the dependencies for my two projects
>   have not been downloaded from the central repository before.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

This is the Pom.xml
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Test</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.MyBundle</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyBundle</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please include your pom.xml - it could be easier to understand the problem then.

Comment: When you say the other two projects are "installed" in your local repo, do you mean that you used 'mvn install' command on them? Side note, eclipse does a lot of "magic" for you, one thing being using projects from your workspace to fill in maven dependencies.

Comment: Yes used mvn install:install -file command to install the MyBundle jar into the local repository and it was successful.  But now I have this problem that I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Local repo needs to be defined as repo in your POM (if we are talking about custom folder and not the default defined in your settings.xml - by default `${user.home}/.m2/repository`).

Comment: No I mean the local repo defined in the settings.xml.  MyBundle jar was installed in the com folder of the local repo.

Comment: What folders do you have in your `~/.m2/repository/com/MyBundle/MyBundle`? Is there a folder `0.0.1` with a POM and JAR inside it?

Comment: Yes I have folder 0.0.1 and inside it are two files MyBundle-0.0.1.jar.lastUpdated and MyBundle-0.0.1.pom.lastUpdated

Comment: That is empty directory... those files are just maven's internal metadata to say when it was checking for the artifact last time. Do the `mvn install` again.

Comment: so does it mean the install was not successful?

Comment: Yes or you have incorrect groupId / artifactId.

Comment: Did the reinstall and now I have these files in 0.0.1 folder _remote.repositories , MyBundle-0.0.1.jar  and MyBundle-0.0.1.pom  but I still have the same problem.